# How to put extra data in a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I want to register a callback for `dialog.setOnCancelListener ( OnCancelListener)`, 
but this callback will be registered many times for other dialogs,So I should get some unique date from  passed dialog with different extra date to know which one is useful or unuseful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interface, put this code in your Dialog Fragmnet:
        public static interface MyInterface {
        public void cance(String someInfo);
    }

```
private MyInterface mListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mListener = (MyInterface) activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mListener = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Then, in the onCancel method:

```
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCancel(dialog);
            //This line passes the String to the implementing class
            mListener.onChoose(choice);
}
```

Back in your class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onChoose(String myExtraData) {
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: where the function onAttach defined?

Comment: When you see @Override it means that is an inherited method from the super class. Essentially, onAttach is a part of the interface class, much like onCreate is a part of the Activity class.